# Pandas read_excel doesn't parse dates correctly - returns a constant date instead

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-parsing, xlsb

I've read a .xlsb file and parsed date columns using a code below:

```
dateparser = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)

data = pd.read_excel(r"test.xlsb", engine="pyxlsb",
                 parse_dates=["start_date","end_date"],
                 date_parser=dateparser
                 )
```

My input columns in the .xlsb file have format **DD/MM/YYYY** (e.g. 26/01/2008). As an output of the above-mentioned code I get, for example: **1970-01-01 00:00:00.000038840**. Only the last 5 digits changes.

If I read the same file without parsing dates, the same columns are of float64 type and containing only the last 5 digits of output before (e.g. **38840.0**).

I assume this is a problem associated with date encoding itself. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if you were able to figure out the answer to this problem. But, below is how I resolved it:

```
from pyxlsb import convert_date

self.data: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_excel(self.file, sheet_name=self.sheet, engine='pyxlsb', header=0)
self.data["test"] = self.data.apply(lambda x: convert_date(x.SomeStupidDate), axis=1)
```

More details can be found here: https://pypi.org/project/pyxlsb/ by doing ctrl+F for "convert_date".

Comment: It's a shame that `pyxlsb` operates this way.  I often face use cases where I wouldn't know in advance that a column in a sheet is supposed to be a date, and `pyxlsb` reading it as a float means having to depend on the column name actually including "date", or some other signifier.  Other Excel engines don't have this issue.